# What is the difference between Container and Paravirtualization?

Tags: docker, lxc

A representative example of container is LXC (now it may be Docker.)

LXC is called container-virtualization.
Xen is called para-virtualization.

But LXC is not called paravirtualization, and Xen is not called containers.

What is the difference between the two techniques?
Is there a technical difference in implementing two virtualization?

Answer (score 0):

Although containers and virtual machines are similar resources,they have somehow different approach.
Virtualization- resources like CPU,RAM,networking are somehow 'virtualized down to the hardware' and represent multiple separate resources.

Containers-represent layers above the OS level. With Docker containers all dependancies are inside one container. That suit for microservices,where you separate Node.js,Python or Psql resources into separate containers which can communicate each other. Containers pros are speed,cause they are lightweight(especially with multistage build),but there are also security risks,they share the hardware and many images can be compromised so exploit in one container leads to security risk for others.

Image from [Medium article](https://medium.com/@kritika.singhal/containerization-vs-virtualization-5aff7495b300)

[image]